# How to get add FAX number to lotus notes contacts? what exact pName to use?

Tags: c#, interop, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I am creating names.nsf from mapicontact. what will the pName for Fax number, Mobile Number for offie fax and home fax. I am doing like -

`notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("OfficePhoneNumber", "34534534534534");                            notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("PhoneNumber", "556862555");`

What will be the pName form Faxnumber and mobile number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the item/field name of specific values in a form.
If you have a Domino Designer Client this is quite easy to find out: Just open your names.nsf in Designer, then open the form "Person" and you can read the field names from the form design.

If your addressbook version is greater than version 9, then you need to open one of the Subforms "(V1xPersonSubform)" instead and get the item names / field names from there.

If you do not have a designer, then just manually create a document in your address book and fill the field with the desired value and save it. Then press Alt + Enter to open the document properties. On the second tab of the properties there are all item values and by clicking them one after the other you can find the one containing your entered value.
[image: Property box to find out item names]

The direct answer to your question is:

```
Fax = OfficeFaxPhoneNumber  
mobile number = CellPhoneNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. able to work with it. thanks a ton